# How would I get a ListView from ListActivty INSIDE a class that extends on TabActivity?

Tags: android, listview, tabs, listactivity, tabactivity

Newbie here, bear with me..

I have a class that extends TabActivity. One of my tabs currently contains one long string composed of some records i got from my sqlite table. Now i'm following a tutorial and the next step is to move away from the string and create something a bit more appropriate for the records, a listView. However it says i'll need to change my class to extend ListActivity but i've already extended TabActivity (not part of the tutorial)and i don't really have the knowledge yet to know where to go from here.

**I figure if my tabs content was set with intents to separate classes I wouldn't have a problem but it's important to me that both the tabs and their content are constructed in the same class because i will want to be doing a lot between them later.** But maybe there is no way i can avoid creating a separate class? If so could i still point both of my tabs towards the same class? for the same reason as above. But then how would i get them still displaying different content?

I sure there's an obvious solution but i don't have enough programming experience to have a clue what it is, I've been googling a while now but i'm not really sure what to look for so if somebody could point me in the right direction i'd really appreciate it.

Hope I'm talking sense, **Here's a link to see the class i'm working on:**

[Codeviewer.org , my Budget.java](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:148c)

Comment: Can you provide a better view on your approach? How are you generating your tabs ? Are you setting an intent or adding them dynamically using a TabFactory? Can you provide that link of tutorial you are using.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info! The tutorial's in a book but i've included my main class in my original post. As you'll see my tabs content is just an xml textview id at the moment. which i'm filling in my showBudgetOutcome method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to have your class extend `ListActivity` (or `TabActivity` for that matter) as those classes are just a convenience.

If you want to show a `ListView` in a `TabActivity`, check out this [tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/blog/android-tabactivity-with-two-list-views/) I wrote.

Comment: Oh thank you I think that was exactly what i was looking for! Though i'll need to alter my current code quite a bit, wish me luck haha

Comment: thanks for that tutorial, really usefull and well explained!!

Answer (score 2):

You can always insert a ListView to your activity, give appropriate `android:id` so you may refer it to handle data. Theres no compulsion that a ListView must be in a ListActivity.

See my comments so I can help you more.

Comment: Thanks that's what i was wondering. So on why exactly do we extend ListActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mess with the `TabActivity` as this `Activity` just manages all of your tabs. You just set the new `ListActivity` as the content of the tab you want to display it in.

Check out the Android [Hello Tab View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial as it shows you how to assign an `Activity` to a tab which is just what you need.

Comment: Thanks! But'll this'll mean my tab will point to a separate class (extending ListActivity of course) right? Whereas I really want to try and keep the contents of both tabs within my current class so that its easier later when i want to use the two tabs together! Am i being silly? Alternatively maybe there's a way i can point both tab contents towards the same separate class extending ListActivity but still showing different content I suppose?

Comment: And why would it be harder to do it the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: I'd just read in a few places while researching that it's easier to establish connection between the two tabs if they're created within the same class. Perhaps if i quickly tell you that i'm aiming for an income tab, with sources and amounts of money, and and outcome tab, with the same. And then even as the user switches between the two they would have a running total displayed at the bottom showing total costs and whether they've projected more money it the outcome than the income ect.

Comment: It just seemed appropriate to keep them together for what i wanted. sensible? nonsense?

Comment: The placement of your classes has nothing to do with the work logic. You have to learn and understand how the Java class and access system works and how to pass data between classes otherwise you are not going to get far with Android development.

Comment: Yes i know I'll certainly need to learn that :) but i don't want to do that just for the sake of getting the hang of it, i'm just trying to implement the approach that seems more appropriate to what i plan to do (I wish i could find some of the references i'd been reading so it wouldn't sound like i'm talking out of my ass here haha). But thank you for the advice! I assure you i'm not trying to avoid learning about passing data between classes, i'll get there!